# @Binding and ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, data-binding, binding, swiftui

I can't undertand how to use `@Binding` in combination with `ForEach` in SwiftUI. Let's say I want to create a list of `Toggle`s from an array of booleans.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var boolArr = [false, false, true, true, false]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(boolArr, id: \.self) { boolVal in
                Toggle(isOn: $boolVal) {
                    Text("Is \(boolVal ? "On":"Off")")
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to pass a binding to the bools inside the array to each `Toggle`. The code here above gives this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier '$boolVal'

And ok, this is fine to me (of course). I tried:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var boolArr = [false, false, true, true, false]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($boolArr, id: \.self) { boolVal in
                Toggle(isOn: boolVal) {
                    Text("Is \(boolVal ? "On":"Off")")
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This time the error is:

> Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires
>   that 'Binding' conform to 'Hashable'

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use something like the code below. Note that you will get a deprecated warning, but to address that, check this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57333200/7786555

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var boolArr = [false, false, true, true, false]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(boolArr.indices) { idx in
                Toggle(isOn: self.$boolArr[idx]) {
                    Text("boolVar = \(self.boolArr[idx] ? "ON":"OFF")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have accepted your answer, I really like the simplicity, but I decided to accept the warning free one. I'm curious to see what Apple we'll do about the subscript(_:) issue. Very likely we'll be able to improve the answers to this question in the future beta releases.

Comment: That's alright. Let's see if next week we have some progress on the matter.

Comment: @superpuccio As mentioned in the linked answer, the beta 6 of Xcode fixed the warning.

Comment: @kontiki wasnt there something about the index version can only be used if the array's content stays the same?

Comment: This change to using indices also changes ForEach from displaying dynamic content to static content. If you want to remove an element from the list being iterated over, you may get an error. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/3364099-init

Comment: To expand on what @EmmaKAlexandra is saying - your app will crash with an index out of bounds error if you are doing deletions.

Comment: @Austin Please provide solution for the case you mentioned for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't use indices. Bad code. There are red flags all over Swift and SwiftUI docs about this. Indices create bugs. Swift and SwiftUI provide MULTIPLE other means for getting array members. Who gave this a green checkmark?!

Answer (score 71):

#### ⛔️ Don't use a Bad practice!

Most of the answers (including the @kontiki accepted answer) method cause the engine to rerender the entire UI on each change and Apple mentioned this as a bad practice at [wwdc2021](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10018/) (around time 7:40)

---

## ✅ Swift 5.5

From this version of Swift, you can use binding array elements directly by passing in the bindable item like:

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var models = (0...9).map { Model(id: $0) }

    var body: some View {
        List($models) { $model in TextField("Instruction", text: $model.text) }
    }
}
```

⚠️ Note the usage of the `$` syntax for all `$model`s.

Comment: I understand but at least check for OS and don't continue the bad practice @paulz

Comment: Actually, this works well when targeting iOS 14.0 and on; just tested with Xcode 13 beta 3. Not all Swift 5.5 features require iOS 15.

Comment: How do you use .onDelete in this case?

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work. I get ```Cannot declare entity named '$direction'; the '$' prefix is reserved for implicitly-synthesized declarations``` and ```Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that 'Binding<[String]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'``` from $directions

Comment: While this answer might contain some useful info, it's very different from the OP's stated goal of "create a list of Toggles from an array of booleans".

Comment: And then how do I make the binding List searchable?

Answer (score 16):

Update for Swift 5.5

```
struct ContentView: View {
    struct BoolItem: Identifiable {
      let id = UUID()
      var value: Bool = false
    }
    @State private var boolArr = [BoolItem(), BoolItem(), BoolItem(value: true), BoolItem(value: true), BoolItem()]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
            List($boolArr) { $bi in
                Toggle(isOn: $bi.value) {
                        Text(bi.id.description.prefix(5))
                            .badge(bi.value ? "ON":"OFF")
                }
            }
                Text(boolArr.map(\.value).description)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                                    Button(action: { self.boolArr.append(BoolItem(value: .random())) })
                { Text("Add") }
                , trailing:
                Button(action: { self.boolArr.removeAll() })
                { Text("Remove All") })
        }
    }
}
```

Previous version, which allowed to change the number of `Toggle`s (not only their values).

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var boolArr = [false, false, true, true, false]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // id: \.self is obligatory if you need to insert
            List(boolArr.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                    Toggle(isOn: self.$boolArr[idx]) {
                        Text(self.boolArr[idx] ? "ON":"OFF")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading:
                Button(action: { self.boolArr.append(true) })
                { Text("Add") }
                , trailing:
                Button(action: { self.boolArr.removeAll() })
                { Text("Remove All") })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we have something like that but with ForEach and not a list ?

Comment: Of course we can, @GrandSteph, why not?          
      `VStack {
                ForEach(boolArr.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                    Toggle(isOn: self.$boolArr[idx]) {
                        Text(self.boolArr[idx] ? "ON":"OFF")
                    }
                }
            }.padding()`. 
Or `HStack`, or` Group`, `Section`, etc. `List` just has this concise init (with `ForEach` included) since it is a very common thing for it ... to list items.

Comment: Appreciated @Paul but I'm struggling with ForEach and dynamic list of array. I can't seem to satisfy the following 3 conditions : 1 - Dynamic array (indices is meant to be static, removing a element will crash) 2 - Use bindings so I can modify each element in subview  3 - Not use a list (I want custom design, no title etc ...)

Comment: Crash on removal is an issue some people run into when deal with SwiftUI. In some cases using projected value can help: `func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) { $store.wrappedValue.data.remove(atOffsets: offsets) // instead of store.data.remove()  }`. In other cases creating a var using `Binding()` init (not @Binding directive) is the best solution for this kind of issue. But the question is too general, @GrandSteph. Chances are you'll get a better answer if formulate it properly here at SO. Also you can check some variants of array driven interfaces here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59739983/

Comment: And then how do I make the binding List searchable?

Answer (score 8):

In SwiftUI, just use **Identifiable** structs instead of Bools

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var boolArr = [BoolSelect(isSelected: true), BoolSelect(isSelected: false), BoolSelect(isSelected: true)]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(boolArr.indices) { index in
                Toggle(isOn: self.$boolArr[index].isSelected) {
                    Text(self.boolArr[index].isSelected ? "ON":"OFF")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BoolSelect: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var isSelected: Bool
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't actually really like the creation of a struct to wrap a simple bool value (since I could have used \.self to identify the bool itself), but your answer is warning free, so probably is the right answer at the moment (let's keep an eye on what Apple we'll do with the subscript(_:) issue) ps: the "Hashable" is actually redundant in the BoolSelect definition.

Comment: This seems to be broken now. The code above gives "Type of expression is ambiguous without context" in XCode 11 beta 2.

Comment: And yet it seems to me that the latest Xcode can not handle the likes of "ForEach($boolArr)". I also get the "`type of expression is ambiguous without more context`"-error. When using a custom View in the ForEach loop and passing the loop variable as a `@Binding` the compiler finds yet another problem "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ForEach<_, _, _>' with an argument list of type '`(Binding<[MyIdentifiable]>, @escaping (MyIdentifiable) -> MyCustomView)`'"

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to get something like this to work for hours. The key for me was to use "indices" as the array to loop through.

Comment: Won't work if we have an array of `Identifiable` inside a `@State` struct and need to iterate over it. Will have to to use `List(model.boolArr.indices, id: \.self)` anyway if we plan to insert or remove array elements.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me. Ive tried with observable objects manually sending updates and even accessing the array directly like procedural swift. But using .indices was the only thing that worked after stumping me for days. Surely SwiftUI will adapt to iterate over a @State array without loosing the reference to the UI?!

Answer (score 4):

In WWDC21 videos Apple clearly stated that using `.indices` in the `ForEach` loop is a bad practice. Besides that, we need a way to uniquely identify every item in the array, so you can't use `ForEach(boolArr, id:\.self)` because there are repeated values in the array.

As @Mojtaba Hosseini stated, new to Swift 5.5 you can now use binding array elements directly passing the bindable item. But if you still need to use a previous version of Swift, this is how I accomplished it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var boolArr: [BoolItem] = [.init(false), .init(false), .init(true), .init(true), .init(false)]
  
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(boolArr) { boolItem in
        makeBoolItemBinding(boolItem).map {
          Toggle(isOn: $0.value) {
            Text("Is \(boolItem.value ? "On":"Off")")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  struct BoolItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var value: Bool
    
    init(_ value: Bool) {
      self.value = value
    }
  }
  
  func makeBoolItemBinding(_ item: BoolItem) -> Binding<BoolItem>? {
    guard let index = boolArr.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id }) else { return nil }
    return .init(get: { self.boolArr[index] },
                 set: { self.boolArr[index] = $0 })
  }
}
```

First we make every item in the array identifiable by creating a simple struct conforming to `Identifiable`. Then we make a function to create a custom binding. I could have used force unwrapping to avoid returning an optional from the `makeBoolItemBinding` function but I always try to avoid it. Returning an optional binding from the function requires the map method to unwrap it.

I have tested this method in my projects and it works faultlessly so far.