# Editbutton deletes items (with Bindings) from List in a funny way in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, binding, swiftui, swiftui-list, observableobject

I'm giving up. Here's the problem: I try to load an array `names` as an ObservableObject in my List. The names must be connected as `Bindings` to the TextField:

```
class Users: ObservableObject {
    @Published var names = ["Adele", "Taylor", "Michael"]
}
```

My ContentView looks like this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var users: Users
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<users.names.count, id: \.self) {
                TextField("titel", text: $users.names[$0])
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        .navigationTitle("bug")
    }
}
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    users.names.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
}
```

The environmentObject is linked to the ContentView():

```
ContentView()
.environmentObject(Users())
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to delete a row, it looks funny: The row below slides to the right and the row which should be deleted moves upwards. It's even not consistent but depends on which item I start deleting on. See this .gif:

[image: Bug in SwiftUI List]

### What I've tried so far:

I think the bug has something to do with the list not being Identifiable. So I tried using something like:

```
ForEach(users.names, id: \.id) {
    ...
}
```

With a new Users class with an `id: UUID()`
But using the objects themselves and not `0..<users.names.count` only leads to the problem, that I can't use a Binding in my ForEach-Loop. See also:
[@Binding and ForEach in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340575/binding-and-foreach-in-swiftui)

So my questions are:

- Do I miss something here? I'm new to SwiftUI so there's a big chance I don't get a fundamentally thing.
- Can I use a Binding in an ForEach-Loop while also using an `UUID` as an id (**not**: `id: \.self`) ?
- Can I make the items in an ForEach-Loop so identifiable, that there are no visual bugs when deleting them while also using `ForEach(0..<users.names.count, id: \.self)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerated` to access both the `element` and its `index`:

```
ForEach(Array(users.names.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, element in
    // use either `index` or `element` here
}
```

You can also use this [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63083658/8697793) to make sure you don't access non-existing bindings when deleting items.

Comment: And their `Binding` would look something like: `Binding<String>(get: { element }, set: { users.names[index] = $0 })`

Comment: Thank you very much! I needed both hints to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [@pawello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8697793/pawello2222) and [@George_E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9607863/george-e) my working code now looks like this:

```
struct UserWithUUID: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
}

class Users: ObservableObject {
    @Published var names = [UserWithUUID(id: UUID(), name: "Taylor"), UserWithUUID(id: UUID(), name: "Swift")]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var users: Users
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(users.names.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { index, element in
                    TextField("titel", text: Binding<String>(get: { element.name }, set: { users.names[index].name = $0 }))
                }
                .onDelete(perform: delete)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
            .navigationTitle("working")
        }
    }
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        users.names.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```