# SwiftUI avoid ForEach rendering all items when only one changes

Tags: optimization, swiftui, foreach, view

I'm using a `ForEach` to loop over an array of structures and display a `View` for each item of the array.
When I'm mutating a single item, the main view re-render every element of the array. Is there a way to avoid this when using structures? I'd like that only the view corresponding to my modified item to be re-rendered.

Is it achievable with structures or do I need to use classes with `ObservedObjects` ?

A simplified version would look like this (the real version uses the [Defauts package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Defaults) with an array and the item view is way more expensive, but the idea is the same).

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Player {
    var name: String
    var score: Int
}

struct PlayerView: View {
    @Binding var player: Player
    
    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()
        return HStack(spacing: 12) {
            Text(player.name).font(.system(size: 20))
            Text("\(player.score)").font(.system(size: 20))
            Button("plus") { player.score += 1 }.font(.system(size: 20))
        }
    }
}

struct PlayersView: View {
    @State var players = [
        Player(name: "John", score: 12), 
        Player(name: "Jane", score: 15)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach($players, id: \.name) { player in
                PlayerView(player: player)
            }
            Button("inc", action: {players[0].score += 10})
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(PlayersView())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make model `Equatable` so rendering engine could detect if dependent property is really changed.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

```
struct Player: Equatable {    // << here !!
    var name: String
    var score: Int
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank for your quick response. I tried but the `Self._printChanges()` still display two lines when I change one score.

Comment: Test on Simulator or real device, that might be playground issue. As I mentioned I tested and only one is called, at least with provided example - your real code might have different additional affected areas.

Comment: I did conformed everything to `Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable` but they are still re-rendered. I'm also getting a couple of `@440` when using `_printChanges` but I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: @Vincent Take a look at this , I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891839/14871052

Comment: This solution did not work for me either