# How to pass a binding variable inside foreach by SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to pass a binding variable inside foreach.

```
struct Users: View {
    let users: [User]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(users){ user in
            NavigationLink(destination: UserEdit(user: user), label: {
                UserMemberCell(user: user)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct UserEdit: View {
    @Binding var user:User

    init(user:Binding<User>){
        self._user = user
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(user.name)
    }
}
```

Because the user property's change should pass in any related views.
`users` array is just `let` array. and `user` is also not publisher.

How to wrap user into user's binding variable in ForEach.

Comment: Duplicate. [@Binding and ForEach in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340575/binding-and-foreach-in-swiftui). Also, do not post partial code that does not compile. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I use just `let` array. The link you gave uses `publisher`. How do I resolve my code?

Comment: That question seems like nonsense to me. Where do you see "`publisher`"?

Comment: You can't have a `let` you need to reference your source of truth with `Binding` watch Demystify SwiftUI you haven't provided enough information to give you a specific answer