# SwiftData list bindings with @Query

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

Since Swift 5.5 we could create SwiftUI lists with bindings like this (e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67891839/921573)):

```
class Item {
    // ...
    var isOn: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items: [Item] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach($items) { $item in     // <--- list binding
                    Toggle(isOn: $item.isOn) {
                        Text("Vibrate on Ring")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to do something similar with SwiftData but I get an error:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach($items) { $item in //   <--- Cannot find '$items' in scope
    // ...
```

How can I render a list of SwiftData objects that allows inline editing of objects through bindings?

Comment: You have to use Bindable with the new frameworks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can utilize the new [`Bindable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bindable), which has a subscript operator to wrap the underlying data into a binding variable:

```swift
ForEach(items) { item in
    Toggle(isOn: Bindable(item).isOn) { ... }
}
```

---

If the binding need to be reused multiple times, you can also create the `Bindable` object within the view:

```swift
ForEach(items) { item in
    @Bindable var item = item
    Toggle(isOn: $item.isOn) { ... }
}
```

Note the usage of `$`, since the bindable object is created as a property wrapper.

Comment: Correct, it's even in the docs although its on 2 lines instead of 1.

Comment: Hi, malhal. Do you have a link to that example in the documentation?

Comment: @MikikoJane Have added an example of using it in 2 separate lines. Similar example can be found at [`Bindable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/bindable)

Answer (score 9):

The easiest solution I found is to use @Bindable *and* to separate the `Query` macro and the `Bindable` into different views.

An example

```
struct ItemRow: View {
    @Bindable var item: Item
   
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(item.name)
            Toggle(isOn: $item.isOn) // Notice the $
        }
    }
}
```

Calling view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ItemRow(item: item)
     //...
}
```

Comment: This is beta, requires SwiftData and the new OS versions coming fall 2023.

Comment: Yes of course, the whole question is about beta versions so what is your point?

Comment: It's just to clarify, as this may not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: Ok but why not clarify that for the whole question then, that’s what made me react.

Comment: You're right, that's true...

Answer (score 0):

Swift Bindable Structure can be used like the example given below.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Toggle(isOn: Bindable(item).isOn) {
                        Text("Vibrate on Ring")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```