# Swift Data how to get binding from @Query property?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I want to use `List(data:, editActions:, rowContent:)`, the `data:` needs a $property, but I can't pass `$persons` in there directly. Is there any way to solve like this below:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct BindableTest: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var persons: [Person]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add") {
                let person = Person(name: "test", age: 12)
                modelContext.insert(person)
            }
            
            List($persons, editActions: .all) { $person in
                Text(person.name)
                
                Text(person.age.formatted())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I saw this question is similar to my question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464884/swiftdata-list-bindings-with-query`, but those answers don't suit my situation.

Comment: Binding to a Query is impossible, it is read only and Binding is for value types. Person is a reference.